# Enable/ disable a raisebutton according to the textform field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to enable a button when the textformfield is not empty and disable a button when the textformfield is empty.

```
bool isEnabled = false;
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
RaisedButton(
                // disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                child: Text("Click"),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      isEnabled = true;
                    } else
                      isEnabled = false;
                  });
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Right now, what you are doing is wrong, because you can not enable a disabled button using `onPressed`.*

It should be done like,
Inside `TextFormField`, set value of `isEnabled` to `true` is input text length is greater than zero, `false` otherwise.

```
        TextFormField(
            onChanged: (text) {
                setState(() {
                  if(text.length>0)
                     isEnabled=ture;
                  else
                     isEnabled=false;
                  });
            }
```

and then disable/enable button like this,

```
onPressed: isEnabled?
    (){
     //do something
   } 
: null;// or pass blank (){}
```

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to run this on a simulator. This code is only working when I am saving and refreshing the file. I don't know why it is not showing up immediately when the text is being typed in the textformfield.

Comment: Code inside onchanged must be inside setState

Answer (score 0):

Here's example that answers your question. It also changes the color of the button to indicate disabled or other wise.

```
bool isEnabled = false;
//Initialize a button color variable
Color btnColor = Colors.grey;
```

...

```
TextFormField(
        onChanged: (text) {
            setState(() {
              if(text.length>0)
                 {
                  isEnabled=true;
                 btnColor = Colors.blue; //update active colour
           }   else{
                 isEnabled=false;
                 btnColor = Colors.grey; //update active colour
            }
          });
        }

RaisedButton(
            color: btnColor,
            disabledColor: Colors.grey,
            child: Text("Click"),
            onPressed:  isEnabled?
(){
 //do something
} 
: null;

)
```

Comment: In this case, as soon as I call setState the page is rerendered and the keyboard disappears and the TextFormField becomes empty. But how to change the colour leaving the keyboard on the screen and not clearing the input field?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the accepted answer and at least in my case this solution did not work: The setState rebuilds the screen and therefore I always get an empty TextField.

What you can do is wrap the Button in a Listener:

```
        ValueListenableBuilder<TextEditingValue>(
          valueListenable: _textEditingController,
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Click"),
              onPressed: value.text.isNotEmpty
                  ? () {
                    }
                  : null,
            );
          },
        ),
```

The Widget does as expected: It listens to your TextEditingController changes and then rebuilds the button.